# Cannot have friend with auto

Tags: c++11, friend

```
    struct X
    {

    private:
        int value_;
    public:
        X():value_(int())
        {}
        X(int value):value_(value)
        {}
        friend
            //int operator+(X lhs, X rhs);//THIS WILL WORK  
//BUT THE ONE BELOW WON'T
        auto operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)->decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_);

    };


    auto operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)->decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_)
    {//If I change return type to "not auto" there is no problem with friendship
        return lhs.value_ + rhs.value_;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        X a(5);
        X b(6);
        cout << a + b;
        return 0;
    }
```

Cannot declare a friendship with operator+ in scenario when return type is auto. Any solution for that?

Comment: Not actually anything to do with friendship or with auto. The problem is that in the decltype, the compiler thinks that X is an incomplete class. I'm not sure if it is right or wrong about this.

Comment: Which compiler are you using. I can get your example with some minor changes to work. But only on gcc. The msvc seems to be buggy in this case.

Comment: mkaes I have both gcc 4.6 and VS2010 sp1 and on both of them it won't compile in this form

Comment: @unapersson well, obviously the compiler is wrong for class has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a compiler bug rather than anything intentional (which compiler? consider filing a bug). However, you can always do the ugly alternative described in the [specification for `auto` with functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2541.htm) (of course avoiding that is motivation for the new syntax, but if it does not work...), namely:

```
decltype((*(X*)0).value_ + (*(X*)0).value_)
```

You have the same X on both sides, so you can make a typedef in X so you don't have to type out this obnoxiousness both in declaration and definition of the operator.

(Edit) For cases where you don't have the same X on both sides, you can still factor the declaration so that it's not too horrible by preparing a template (trait) with the decltype and using it to declare the operator. Something like:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
struct PlusType {
    typedef decltype((*(X*)0).value_ + (*(Y*)0).value_) Type;
}

template <typename X, typename Y>
PlusType<X, Y>::Type operator+(X &x, Y &y);
```

Comment: unfortunately this is just demo sample, original code is bit more complicated, if you wish I can update it but general gist is of the form that X is a template with param IntType so this operator+ would ideally add two "different" object types X<int> and X<long> for example. That's why the decltype.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I have edited the answer and added sample of how to wrap the ugly decltype in a template trait for use in more complex cases.

Comment: @Vlad: Care to explain why? It's taken directly from the proposed specification.

Comment: Proposed spec and what is implemented might be different things. In fact, this won't work for GCC. Could be a bug, could be something else - I don't know. Solution provided by @unapersson works.

Answer (score 1):

This works with g++ 4.5.1:

```
class X {
   ...


    friend auto operator+( const X & a, const X & b )->decltype( X::value_ + X::value_  );
};

auto operator+( const X & a, const X & b )->decltype( X::value_ + X::value_) {
    return a.value_ + b.value_;
}
```

Comment: +1. It works. The only thing that concerns me is that this usage doesn't make much sense at all. `X` is well known, no templates involved. I'd prefer going with non-C++0x solution by providing read-only accessors, or having operator a class member.

Comment: Assuming you've left `X::value_` non-`static`, then the fact that this *works* appears to me like a bug...

Comment: But it does not work on microsoft msvc. I guess the OP has found a compiler issue.

Comment: @Vlad I think that I will go with pre c++0x solution but to me it seems that VS has ZERO new features defined which are not buggy. I myself filed bugs on lambdas, static_assert, decltype and rvalues.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do : Generally speaking, *many* of those bugs in VC++ 2010 were actually bugs in the standard draft it was modeling (N3000). As VC++ 11 will presumably be based on N3290, many of those bugs will be fixed by virtue of modeling the updated (read: fixed) standard.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in your situation, using auto does not make all that much sense, you would be probably better off saying the operator returns int.

The issue here is that in order to be able to write rhs.value_ rhs must be an instance of a complete type. The type X is considered complete after the closing } of the class. So the compiler is rightfully complaining.

EDIT3:

Since it seems to me my above explanation was not complete and could lead to confusion.

```
struct X
{

   //code ommited for brevity...
   //at this line one has decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_) where 
   //lhs and rhs are of type X however the X type is not yet complete. 
   //The compiler has to however determine the type of the friend including 
   //the return type...
   friend auto operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)-> decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_);
};
```

EDIT:

For a discussion on VS2010 relating to decltype that explains why it is the way it is in VS2010 and also explains why it is standard compilant how it is in VS2010 you can look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/21e7e01a-ae32-4b20-bc80-3102bb3b8f57/):

My first option would be to drop auto. However, assuming you have provided a simpler example for illustration, and in your real case auto would actually make sense you could try:

```
struct X
{
private:
    int value_;
public:
    X() : value_(int()) { }

    X(int value):value_(value) { }

    template <typename T>
    auto operator+(const T& rhs) -> decltype(value_ + rhs.value_)
    {
        return value_ + rhs.value_;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    X a(5);
    X b(6);
    std::cout << a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2:

For completness (and to illustrate this is not an issue with auto and friend but rather attempting to use an incomplete type consider the following code (that also achieves what you want but in a twisted not recommendable way :-) ):

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
public:
        X() : value_(int())     { }

        X(int value):value_(value) { }

        int value_;

};

struct A : public X
{
        friend auto operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) -> decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_);
};

auto operator+(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) -> decltype(lhs.value_ + rhs.value_)
{
        return lhs.value_ + rhs.value_;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        X a(5);
        X b(6);
        std::cout << a + b;

        return 0;
}
```

The code compiles ok in VS2010 and gcc-4.5.1

Comment: @ds27680 thanks for your answer, your saying "So the compiler is rightfully complaining" - I dissagree. I dissagree for the reason that the X type is being accessed from outside (from friend), and that's why I believe that this is a compiler bug. But thanks for your answer and for link provided, going to read it now.

Comment: @ds27680 another problem with your approach is that you have to have public access in X and that unacceptable.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do Well the second example is there only to prove that this is not an issue related to auto and making the operator friend not a solution. I proposed you a solution before that makes the operator a templated member of the class. This works ok in VS2010, but for some reason it does not compile ok in gcc 4.5.1 (on ideone) (although in my opinion it should) :-)

Comment: @There is nothing we can do About the compiler rightfully (or not in your opinion) complaining, the problem is in the friend declaration from X, not in the operator definition outside of X. The friend declaration attempts to use X as it were a complete type but in that context X is not a complete type yet.

Comment: @ds within operator+ type X is complete.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do What about the friend declaration from X? Is there X complete? I would say no it isn't...

Comment: @ds the X type is complete. friend by it's nature says that function is from outside of class definition, so it must be complete by the time friend is being defined.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do Once more, I am not talking about the definition but rather about the friend declaration from the X body. In VS2010 the error about the incomplete type is on the line of the friend declaration, not on the actual definition of the + operator outside of X

Comment: @There is nothing we can do Have you re-read my proposal? (first code snippet). Is there any reason why you cannot make the + operator a templated member of the X struct?

Comment: @ds yes the approach with operator+ as a member would work and I have nothing against it. The only thing I'm objecting to is that compiler complains that type isn't complete when in fact the type is complete. And yes I also talk about friend declaration. Just because this declaration is inside of X it doesn't mean that X isn't finished at the time it is used (by operator+)

Comment: @There is nothing we can do Well let's recap. You have two different compilers VC2010 and gcc 4.5.1 (or 4.6) telling you the same thing about the friend declaration (use of incomplete type). I bet the Intel compiler 11.1 or better will tell you the same thing. What is the probability that three compilers from three different sources have a bug and complain for no reason? I would say 0... That being said I must say I partially understand your frustration about it, I would also like it if it would just worked. On the other hand I also see several reasons why it is the way it is.

Comment: @ds To me it is just illogical that compiler complains about type being incomplete when in fact this type has been completed. It imposes unnatural constraint on the design. The whole point in this example is to have operator+ as a friend to avoid fnc call to getValue() for example. If I wouldn't need that I wouldn't need that friend'ship' either.